# How to copy object in Google Cloud Storage and preserving the ACL with JSON REST API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, move, acl

I'm trying to copy an existing object in Google Cloud Storage using JSON REST API, but to preserve the existing ACL.

I found I can do this with 2 requests to the server, but is there another way in which only one request to the server is sent? This is how I do it now:

```
Storage.Objects.Get getRequest = storage.objects().get(bucketName, fileName).setProjection("full");

StorageObject file = getRequest.executeUnparsed().parseAs(StorageObject.class);

Rewrite renamed = storage.objects().rewrite(bucketName, fileName, bucketName, newFileName, file);

renamed.executeUnparsed();
```